# Make [azure-graph-api] a synonym of [azure-ad-graph-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are a medium number of questions being asked in [azure-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-graph-api) which is the same as [azure-ad-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-graph-api). My request is to make [azure-ad-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad-graph-api) the master tag, and have [azure-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-graph-api) be a synonym of that master tag.